# How to use DateTime datatype in SQLite Using Room?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I am using  SQLite database with multiple tables. Many of them have columns of type DATETIME.

I have started migrating my database to Room. But I don't know what data type to use in entity class to create DATETIME type of column in table.

Answer (score 5):

**You need to use TypeConvertor**

Define Type convertor as below

```
public class TimestampConverter {
    static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.TIME_STAMP_FORMAT);

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date fromTimestamp(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            try {
                return df.parse(value);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Add `@TypeConverters` annotation to the Field with date type

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "created_date")
@TypeConverters({TimestampConverter.class})
public Date createDate;
```

Comment: This approach creates column datatype as TEXT and not DATETIME. So how can i create column with type DATETIME? Also there is method to convert string to Date in typeconverter but not Date to String. So how Date to String conversion will takes place?

Comment: SQLite has no DATETIME datatype like MySQL or other SQL implimentations. I think you are already using strings. Anyway, TypeConvertor as in the answer is the standard method in Room. I suggest using timestamp as INTEGER rather than TEXT.

Comment: Not able to resolve TIME_STAMP_FORMAT. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: define whatever time format you want to use.

Comment: @Gentleman use this `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: If I want to delete rows which are older than 5 days, can I use this approach to save datetime first? What is the sql of delete query?